# Platform Selection for management Application

Tags: php, .net, platform

Hi there
I am desktop application developer but now i have to work on a School Management Application that needs to be web based.
It has mainly features

two login types School Administration and Students/Parents.
School administrations will upload students Attendance ,Marks in quizzes ,performance etc

and parents or students would be able to down load the data and view that.

this seems preety straight forward but i want to know that what platform should be used?

ZEND framework
PHP
ASP.Net 
or any other.

basically i have very less experience in php like stuff and have relatively much experience in c#,Wpf

**what would you recommend that suits best?**

****also i want to know what you as a professional would use.so that if necessary I can switch ****

Please Rate according to

1. flexibility
2. Scalability
3. Availability of open source components

Comment: for such task considering you don't have web development exeprience you should really decline this offer. imo

Comment: @yes123 no, no, no! Everybody gets started somewhere, and this sounds like a great opportunity for Afnan to learn web development.

Comment: @yes123 Actually i donot have any offer but i am starting to have step in web development.I was afraid that i havent done something so thought of making an app that was my dream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many technical choices for accomplishing this. In this situation, I would recommend using the technology that you already know -- .Net and C#.

re your criteria, is scalability really a big issue? Aren't we talking about hundreds of users, not millions?

And open source components? I don't think you really need them. This application will require some good thinking about security and about database design and UI design. Open source -- using somebody else's code -- doesn't help you address these issues. No matter whose code it is, you still must be certain you have the security worked out.

There is a lot of helpful information about ASP.Net [here](http://www.asp.net/get-started), including many excellent [videos](http://www.asp.net/web-forms).

**Edit**: If you want to go with ASP.Net MVC (a good choice, I think), here is the [main page](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for it, and even better, here are the [videos](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos).

Comment: @Afnan, everybody gets help and encouragement along the way, and we remember that when we are in a position to help someone else. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Actually open source components cans help with security - they can have the benefit of being tested by far more people than you own personal code could. (This however isn't guaranteed - so due diligence is required). And @Afnan - MySpace was also built on a MS tech stack, so big things are very much possible

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go for ASP.NET MVC. PHP is a horrible language compared to C# and other languages. So unless you find a better suitable MVC framework for PHP I'd say ASP.NET MVC is what you want to go with. .NET MVC is also really easy to write tests against, last time I tried it.

1. Flexibility. Only a few things are pre-configured(like default template engines and stuffs) and the rest you can change as much as you like.
2. Scalability. The short answer yes. I.E Stackoverflow runs on .NET MVC. The slightly longer answer is, it depends on you. No web framework scales automatically.
3. I don't know the answer to this one. You have to google it.